# Deleting values in a dictionary containing substring in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains several values (filepaths) belonging to the same key, for a specific task. I want to delete any dictionary values that contain "Converted" within the filepath. This is because I only want to retain the values from the "Submitted" folder.

I have tried several attempts to write something that would do this but there are *not any examples online. Any help in providing some code to do this task would be much appreciated.

```
# Create empty dictionary 
d = dict()
# Add elements containing multiple values per key 
d["key1"] = ["C:/Users/TAS/Documents/Folder/Converted/script.py"]
d["key1"].append("C:/Users/TAS/Documents/Folder/Submitted/script.py")
d["key2"] = ["C:/Users/TAS/Documents/Folder/Converted/script2.py"]
d["key2"].append("C:/Users/TAS/Documents/Folder/Submitted/script2.py")

# key1,key2
d.keys()
# Filepaths
d.values()

# We want to remove any values from the dictionary containing "Converted" within the filepath
d2 = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if v !='*Converted'}
```

Comment: @Chris_Rands I've tried; d2 = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if 'Converted' not in v} ... but this gives me the same output as d.

Comment: @Chris_Rands, that won't work because 'Converted' is a substring of multiple strings in v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Regular python strings do not support wildcard so you're doing strict match with '*Converted'.

If you want to do it by `dict` comprehension:

```
d2 = {k: list(filter(lambda x: 'Converted' not in x, v)) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Regular looping with `filter`:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = list(filter(lambda x: 'Converted' not in x, v)
```

Regular looping with `list` comprehension.

```
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = [path_ for path_ in v if 'Converted' not in path_]
```

Comment: mmm i think this will contains only the last k:v pair, doesnt append into a list all values

Comment: You `filter` predicates need only return a boolean, so `lambda x: 'Converted' not in x` is sufficient.